# Let $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B, m)$ be $\Bbb R$ with Lebesgue measure on Borel sets. Evaluate the measure of a few sets.

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B, m)$ be the measure space $\Bbb R$, with $\mathcal B$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $m$ the Lebesgue measure. Evaluate:

$m([−3,5]) =\boxed ?$

$m(\{0,1,2,3\}) =\boxed ?$

$m([0,2] \cup [4,8]) =\boxed ?$

Comment: Took me some time to realize that $\mathrm{IR}$ is meant to represent $\Bbb R$

Comment: Welcome Sam. You were taught this, and introduced to Lebesgue’s measure how, exactly? It is important to provide *context,thoughts and workings* so that people here can help you constructively. From my perspective right now it is impossible to understand what you’re struggling with